# Using WSPBuilder Tool with SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, wspbuilder

How can I disable all of my features in SharePoint using the WSPBuilder tool without doing it one by one manually?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that with WSPBuilder.
You can use [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=22762#DownloadId=57473) to easily disable Site Features in an Explorer-like view, or write a PowerShell or .NET code to acomplish that.